# How can I script/automate the creation of a mail profile in control panel?

Tags: email, automation, outlook

I was wondering if there was a way to script the creation of a mail profile when a new user logs on to a certain machine.

Emails and windows have the same login creds in our domain, first.last@x.com and first.last for windows.  Is there a way I can script it so when a user logs in, it can take those credentials, adds @x.com to the end of it, and finds their mail settings automatically?  Ideally a box would pop up asking for their password and that would be it.

Right now we are manually having to create them every time in control panel when a user signs into a new computer.

I've looked around at a couple different options, and most of them point to the registry where I can add and delete the creds, but I have yet to find actual code to do the trick in our case.  If someone could just put me in the right direction that would be great!